# Expected Expression Error when Calling a Function in C

Tags: c, function, random, dice

I'm attempting to work with functions for the first time in C. I'm trying to write a classic roll the dice game that rolls a die 10,000 times and then prints out how many times each number has been rolled using functions.

In the code below I keep getting the error code "Expected expression" when trying to set `result= roll_die (int num_sides);`. It says that it's occurring on the `int`. When I remove `int` I get the error code "Use of undeclared identifier 'num_sides' ". How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int roll_die(int num_sides){
num_sides = rand() % 6;
num_sides = num_sides + 1;
return num_sides;
}

int main(void)
{
srand((int)time(0));
unsigned int counter, result, num1=0, num2=0, num3=0, num4=0, num5=0, num6=0;
unsigned int num_rolls = 10000;
for(counter=0; counter<=num_rolls; counter++)
{
    result = roll_die (num_sides);
    if(result==1)
        num1++;
    else if(result==2)
        num2++;
    else if(result==3)
        num3++;
    else if(result==4)
        num4++;
    else if(result==5)
        num5++;
    else if(result==6)
        num6++;
    else{
        printf("Error occurred. \n"); return 0;
    }
}
printf("Number of 1s rolled: %d \n", num1);
printf("Number of 2s rolled: %d \n", num2);
printf("Number of 3s rolled: %d \n", num3);
printf("Number of 4s rolled: %d \n", num4);
printf("Number of 5s rolled: %d \n", num5);
printf("Number of 6s rolled: %d \n", num6);
}
```

Comment: You need either to replace `num_sides` in `main()` with `6`, or you need to define a variable and initialize it to 6.  You should also use an array `int num[7] = { 0 };` so you can simplify the code — I used 7 so you can still process numbers 1-6 as indexes into the array.

Comment: Also, your function hard-codes 6 as the number of sides and ignores the value passed in (it just uses the parameter as a local variable, ignoring what it was supplied as a value).  You should use something more like `int roll_die(int num_sides) { int result = rand() % num_sides + 1; return result; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the help. Why am I unable to use `num_sides`? I would think it would just take the value of 6 and pass it to the main function

Comment: Wrong flow of control — `main()` calls `roll_die()`, not vice versa.  Inside `main()`, you don't have a variable `num_sides`.  There's one in `roll_die()`, but that is local to the function and not accessible from outside the function (it doesn't even exist when `roll_die()` is not the current function).  You only occasionally (about 1 time in 6) set `num_sides` inside the function to `6`.  But, by the time the value is assigned to `result` in `main()`, there is no longer a variable `num_sides` in existence — because `roll_die()` is no longer an active function.

Comment: "I would think it would just take the value of 6". By what means? Magic?

Comment: @n.m. great comment. Your input was valuable for all parties involved. You're the reason beginners enjoy asking questions about coding because you don't make them feel ignorant for asking what they know is a simple/trivial question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in comments, you need either to replace `num_sides` in `main()` with `6`, or you need to define and initialize a variable (`int num_sides = 6;`).  Your function hard-codes 6 as the number of sides and ignores the value passed in (it just uses the parameter as a local variable, ignoring what it was supplied as a value).

Fixing these two issues leads to code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int roll_die(int num_sides)
{
    int result = rand() % num_sides + 1;
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand((int)time(0));
    unsigned int counter, result, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0, num6 = 0;
    unsigned int num_rolls = 10000;
    for (counter = 0; counter <= num_rolls; counter++)
    {
        result = roll_die(6);
        if (result == 1)
            num1++;
        else if (result == 2)
            num2++;
        else if (result == 3)
            num3++;
        else if (result == 4)
            num4++;
        else if (result == 5)
            num5++;
        else if (result == 6)
            num6++;
        else
        {
            printf("Error occurred. \n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Number of 1s rolled: %d \n", num1);
    printf("Number of 2s rolled: %d \n", num2);
    printf("Number of 3s rolled: %d \n", num3);
    printf("Number of 4s rolled: %d \n", num4);
    printf("Number of 5s rolled: %d \n", num5);
    printf("Number of 6s rolled: %d \n", num6);
}
```

Example output:

```
Number of 1s rolled: 1670 
Number of 2s rolled: 1653 
Number of 3s rolled: 1656 
Number of 4s rolled: 1687 
Number of 5s rolled: 1696 
Number of 6s rolled: 1639
```

You should also use an array instead of the 6 `numX` variables.  For example, using `int num[7] = { 0 };` would allow you to use the value returned by `roll_die()` as an index into the array.  That compresses the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int roll_die(int num_sides)
{
    return rand() % num_sides + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned num[7] = { 0 };
    unsigned num_rolls = 10000;
    int num_sides = 6;
    for (unsigned counter = 0; counter <= num_rolls; counter++)
        num[roll_die(num_sides)]++;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_sides; i++)
        printf("Number of %ds rolled: %d \n", i, num[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output – can you spot any difference from the previous output other than that due to the different random sequence?  There shouldn't be any!

```
Number of 1s rolled: 1705 
Number of 2s rolled: 1651 
Number of 3s rolled: 1653 
Number of 4s rolled: 1616 
Number of 5s rolled: 1631 
Number of 6s rolled: 1745
```

And this makes it easy to generalize for N-sided dice, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int roll_die(int num_sides)
{
    return rand() % num_sides + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num_sides = 6;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        num_sides = strtol(argv[1], 0, 0);
        if (num_sides < 2 || num_sides > 999)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Number of sides of %d is not in the range 2..999\n", num_sides);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    srand(time(0));

    unsigned num[num_sides + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_sides; i++)
        num[i] = 0;

    unsigned num_rolls = 10000;
    for (unsigned counter = 0; counter <= num_rolls; counter++)
        num[roll_die(num_sides)]++;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_sides; i++)
        printf("Number of %ds rolled: %d \n", i, num[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

And, if this program is called `die83`, then a sample run might look like:

```
$ ./die83 8
Number of 1s rolled: 1294 
Number of 2s rolled: 1197 
Number of 3s rolled: 1256 
Number of 4s rolled: 1228 
Number of 5s rolled: 1230 
Number of 6s rolled: 1222 
Number of 7s rolled: 1278 
Number of 8s rolled: 1296 
$
```